# To suppress whole main report when sub report has no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS 2005 report with 4 sub reports embedded.I have a situation where when all the sub reports have empty data the main report is still getting displayed . The main report  has a header with header name coming from main data set,so i am getting only report header with empty page.I am using data driven email subscription to deliver the report.

Is there any way wherein the whole main report can be suppressed when all the sub reports  has no data either during report generation stage or while rendering the reports by email subscription or in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Put the 4 sub reports inside a List container.  Tie the list container to a new dataset you create that will return either one row if there is going to be data in the 4 subreports, or no rows if there will be no data.  Set the no data returned behavior of the List to whatever you want.

Comment: , thanks for your reply.My purpose here is to hide the whole main report not just sub reports.The whole report structure is in tabular format grouped by a key and that key happens to be both main report header and parameter passed to sub reports.I am actually delivering the reports using email based data driven subscription.So, is there any way where i can prevent generation of whole report either at report generation point or prevent email delivery at email subscription point.

Comment: Simple, put everything you want to hide, the whole report even, inside the List container.  However, I don't know if that will prevent email delivery of subscriptions.   That's a different question altogether.